# Why Gotham Globe became Gotham City Gazette in Crisis?

Tags: reference, arrowverse, supergirl, batman-1989

In *Supergirl* S05E09 aka *Crisis on Infinite Earths: Part One* we see *Batman (1989)* universe with Alexander Knox (Robert Wuhl). But the newspaper they show was Gotham City Gazette:

[image]

Rather then famous Gotham Globe from the film series. What was the reason for this change? Is it some rights issue or something else?

Comment: Not only that but they got the name of the paper wrong. The other paper in Gotham is the *Gotham Gazette*...no "City" in the name.